# Unmet Dependencies: libapache2-mod-passenger

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, dependencies

I need to insatll libapache2-mod-passenger on apache2.4

```
root@server:~# apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 ......
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libapache2-mod-passenger : Depends: apache2-mpm-worker (>= 2.2.9-9) but it is not going to be installed or
                                     apache2-mpm-prefork (>= 2.2.9-9) but it is not going to be installed or
                                     apache2-mpm-itk (>= 2.2.9-9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install the mpm-worker it tries to remove apache.

```
apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec apache2-suexec-custom
The following packages will be REMOVED
  apache2 libapache2-mod-php5
The following NEW packages will be installed
  apache2-mpm-worker apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common
0 to upgrade, 3 to newly install, 2 to remove and 10 not to upgrade.
Need to get 1,572 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,356 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

How can I install `libapache2-mod-passenger`?